# "tool diffmerge requires a GUI" when trying to hg merge in Cygwin

Tags: mercurial, cygwin, diffmerge

I'm trying to run `hg merge` on Cygwin, which I've [setup to launch DiffMerge](https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/webhelp/sec__mercurial__windows__cygwin.html) on conflicts.  Despite this, I get dropped into `vimdiff` when I merge.

```
$ hg merge
tool diffmerge requires a GUI
...
```

This error message was introduced in commit [090b1a665901](https://selenic.com/hg/rev/090b1a665901), and defines a GUI-enabled device as a `nt` (Windows) or `mac` (OSX) machine, or one with the `DISPLAY` variable set.  In my Cygwin install, `DISPLAY` is not set, and `os.name` is `posix`.

```
$ [ -z "$DISPLAY" ] && echo NOT SET
NOT SET
$ python -c 'import os; print(os.name)'
posix
```

If I set `DISPLAY` to an arbitrary string, `hg merge` successfully launches DiffMerge:

```
$ DISPLAY=abc hg merge
merging path/to/file
(no more unresolved files)
```

What am I missing?  Is Python incorrectly reporting I'm running on `posix`?  Should Cygwin be setting `DISPLAY`?

I'm using Cygwin 2.0.4 on Windows 7, Mercurial version 3.3, DiffMerge 4.2.0.

Comment: Mercurial under Cygwin?! **The Bad Idea (tm)**

Comment: Cygwin might want to define a display variable. And as you found out, it works if you set one. Remains the question why you use mercurial under cygwin while it runs natively under windows without this overhead

Comment: @planetmaker I don't see how that is the question at all.

Comment: @LazyBadger care to elaborate?  I've never had any problems with it before, and this has worked previously.

Comment: seamlessly... Use **native Mercurial** with **native DiffMerge** with **native integration** (`extdiff` for shell-script is hard perversion). Cygwin now is "running on the rake, which are scattered in very strangest places"

Comment: I'm not sure I'm even able to parse that comment.  What are you quoting from?  Why is `extdiff` perverse? Why is the Cygwin setup, provided directly by DiffMerge, undesirable?